# Files cannot be created under usr/bin on centos7

Tags: linux, permissions, centos

```
[root@localhost bin]# touch a
touch: 无法创建"a": 权限不够
[root@localhost bin]# sudo touch a
touch: 无法创建"a": 权限不够
```

I try to create file on /usr/bin in root, However, the prompt prompts that the permissions are not enough

```
[root@localhost bin]# lsattr
-----------------e- /usr/local
-----------------e- /usr/src
-----------------e- /usr/games
--------------I--e- /usr/include
--------------I--e- /usr/share
--------------I--e- /usr/lib
-----------------e- /usr/lib32
--------------I--e- /usr/bin
--------------I--e- /usr/sbin
[root@localhost bin]#
```

What will cause this